# Observable detail and wavelength of light needed to observe - How they are connected?

Tags: visible-light, waves, wavelength, wave-particle-duality, vision

> **"If we use light to look at the structure of an object, we need to
>   have its wavelength smaller than the size of the details we wish to
>   look at".**

I read this statement in an answer at Physics Stack Exchange and also in some reputed video lectures by some reputed faculty.

My question is: **How the observable detail is connected/related to the wavelength of light used to observe it?**

Could somebody explain it to me? (An intuitive explanation is preferable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular resolution of an imaging system in radians is roughly the wave length divided by the aperture width $\lambda / L$.

So the lateral resolution at distance $d$ is roughly $(\lambda d)/L$

Intuition: This has to do with the total phase shift across the aperture of the (plane) wave impinging on the aperture from a single reflecting point.  If that phase shift is one complete 180 degree cycle the aperture output will be zero (the integral of a single sinusoidal cycle in zero).  This gives the first zero crossing resolution angle.

You can see if the wavelength is larger than the aperture, the first zero crossing resolution angle can not be reached--not even with the reflecting point at 90 degrees off axis.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the intuitive answer. Imagine an object so small that it "fits between" two peaks of a light wave. It is then possible for the beam to be aimed straight at that object but miss hitting it. If the object is bigger than the distance between two peaks then the beam cannot avoid hitting it.